# Sorting a Dictionary by Value then Alphabetically by Key Python3

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like:

```
h=[('a',5), ('f', 3), ('b',3), ('c',3), ('d',1), ('e',4) ]
```

I want it sorted like:

```
[('a',5), ('e',4), ('b',3), ('c',3), ('f',3), ('d',1)]
```

I can solve this with Python 2 with something like this:

```
sortedList= sorted(h.iteritems(),key=lambda(k,v):(-v,k))
```

I can get really close in Python 3 with something like this:

```
import operator
sortedList =sorted(h.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1,0) , reverse=True)
```

but it comes out like this

```
[('a',5), ('e',4), ('f',3), ('c',3), ('b',3),  ('d',1)]
```

How can I reverse the tiebreaker operation?

Comment: The only thing disallowed in py3 is that unpacking in the lambda.  `lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])` works in both versions.

Comment: Python's sort is stable - so you can just sort it twice

Comment: h is a list so you cannot use h.items() in python 3

Answer (score 5):

You can use this call to the sorted function in python 3:

```
sortedList = sorted(h, key=lambda k: (-k[1], k[0]))
```

This will give the same result as the python 2 sorting:

```
[('a',5), ('e',4), ('b',3), ('c',3), ('f',3), ('d',1)]
```